# Do I need to use an API key to make request constantly and want to store it in an SQL database

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, security

I need to store the user's API key in an SQL database. This API key can be revoked or removed anytime from website so it isn't static. Is it okay if I store the API key in plain text in the sql database, or do I need to do something to keep it more secured. I need the API key in the sql database.

Comment: If your API call is a Server-Side operation, I see no harm in keeping it as plain text.

Comment: Yes, I use the API key to make requests to the server and retrieve information. I have the API key currently in a Database. I'm just afraid if someone steals the API key from the DataBase, they can view private information and such.